# Why my Gmail goes partially unencrypted whenever I start writing a new message?

Tags: gmail, security, google-chrome, firefox, encryption

When I enter my Gmail account (Ubuntu precise, Firefox with a few addons—AdBlock, WOT, Ghostery, HTTPS Everywhere) the encryption of the page works normally (snapshot 1), and keeps on doing so until I try to write a new message or open a draft. In this case, the connection goes partially unencrypted while keeping the HTTPS status. Information on security of the page also changes (see snapshot 2). Sorry for the snapshots in italian, I guess they're still understandable, I'll add information/translation if needed.

Snapshot 1:
[image]

Snapshot 2:
[image]

Does anyone have a clue on the possible meaning of this? I’ve searched the web for answers, but to no avail.

I want to add that the same thing also happened with Chromium for Ubuntu and on Chrome.

Comment: Gmail went to HTTPS only some time ago. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 3):

That's a "Mixed Content" problem; meaning that, although the main page was served securely via HTTPS, some of the resources used by the web page were retrieved using insecure HTTP.

The Mozilla Blog [Mixed Content Blocking Enabled in Firefox 23!](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) has much more detail about this issue as well as describing how to configure Firefox to block mixed content:

> (2) To block Mixed Passive Content, open a window or tab in Firefox
>   and enter about:config.  You will get to a page that asks you to
>   promise to be careful.  Promise you will be, and then change the value
>   of security.mixed_content.block_display_content to true by double
>   clicking it.
>
> (3)  In Firefox 23+, Mixed Active Content is blocked by default.  If
>   you are using a Firefox version between 18 and 22, you can block Mixed
>   Active Content by opening a window or tab in Firefox and enter
>   about:config.  You will get to a page that asks you to promise to be
>   careful.  Promise you will be, and then change the value of
>   security.mixed_content.block_active_content to true by double clicking
>   it.

To find out precisely which content is getting sent via HTTP, the Net panel in the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) extension for Firefox will show all of the network requests being made from a web page.